# In Deus Ex:HR DC, can I end the suffering of the Hyron test subject and keep the pacifist achievement?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm currently playing the section that was originally The Missing Link DLC in the Directors' Cut of Deus Ex:HR. When you descend to the ocean floor to Dr Kavanagh's lab, there is a Hyron test subject begging to be allowed to die.

[image: Hyron test subject]

Can I administer the dose and keep the Pacifist achievement?

Comment: good question, but finding an answer to this will be probably be pretty tough.

Comment: Close to impossible I reckon. Given that you do lose the achievement for helping someone else who asks you to end their suffering, I'm guessing that you do lose it. But then again, who knows how tightly the DLC is woven into the game?

Comment: @JohnN Untrue.  For that specific quest, administering the final dose of morphine does NOT hurt your ability to get the Pacifist achievement.  See the wiki for details.

Comment: @MasterSergeantShooterPerson Huh, I guess whatever guide I had checked back when originally playing the game was wrong - thanks for the info, that puts a pretty different colour on this. http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Kevorkian_Complex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having just completed the game and administered the lethal dose, the answer is:

Yes, you can.